# Force Highcharts to use standalone framework instead of jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am currently using Highcharts 3.0.1 with Jquery 1.7.2. I would like to upgrade Jquery to the latest version (3.2.1) but I know even the current version of Highcharts officially only supports version 2.x of Jquery. Since Highcharts does have a standalone framework, can I force it to use that instead of jquery so that I no longer have a dependency on jquery? Or will it automatically use jquery if it is available? Ideally I would like to do this with version 3.0.1 of Highcharts, but I can upgrade to 5.x if necessary.

Comment: Since Highcharts v4.2.0, standalone adapter is build-in and Highcharts no more use jQuery internally. So upgrading Highcharts to v5.0 is recommended :)

Comment: Thanks, does this mean I can use jquery 3.2.1 in my project and still use Highcharts 5.0? Or will it still attempt to use jquery if it is available?

Comment: Highcharts 5 don't use jQuery under the hood and version of jQuery doesn't matter. Highcharts provide a constructor `$(container).highcharts()` but it's due to backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can run two versions of jQuery side by side using jQuery's noconflict method.  This should allow you to upgrade the version of jQuery that you are using independently from the version of jQuery that the framework is using.

See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/.

> If for some reason two versions of jQuery are loaded (which is not recommended), calling $.noConflict( true ) from the second version will return the globally scoped jQuery variables to those of the first version.

Comment: Thanks but I need to update jquery due to security concerns with having an older version. If I still need to load the older version there isn't much point in upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

There's an adapter that allows you to use Highcharts without jQuery. I needed to do this once and it worked fine.

Refer to http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/using-highcharts-without-jquery/ and download the js file.

The pattern to create a chart will be something like this:

```
runOnLoad(function(){
  new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart : {
      renderTo : 'container'
      type     : 'bar'
    },
    // other options
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I was under the impression this would only work if jquery wasn't included in the project. I need to use jquery in my project so removing it is not an option. I will see if this works.

Comment: You don't need to remove jquery from your project. The only difference is that Highcharts won't require it anymore.

Comment: Thanks, will try it out!